# Create a shadow in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

i have a layer ,i need the top half red shadow

my code is

```
Shadow.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               (id)[[[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6] CGColor],
                               (id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor],
                               nil];
    Shadow.startPoint = CGPointMake(0,0.5);
    Shadow.endPoint = CGPointMake(1,0.5);
```

this gives me a left half shadow.
What i have to do to have a top half red shadow

Comment: Did you try reversing the numbers inside your CGPointMake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Shadow.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0);
    Shadow.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,1);
```

This solved my problem.Thanks borrrden